# $\mathbb{C}^2\setminus \{(z,z)\ :\ z\in \mathbb{C}\}$ is path connected.

Tags: general-topology

I am really surprised that why $$ \mathbb{C}^2\setminus \{(z,z)\ :\ z\in \mathbb{C}\} $$ is path connected?

I was thinking that it is same as $\mathbb{R}^4\setminus\mathbb{R}^2.$ But still I am unable to prove that the above space is path connected.

Comment: That is because you are removing a plane from a hypercube - somewhat like removing a diagonal from a cube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you want a path from $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$ within $\mathbb{C}^2\setminus\mathrm{diag}(\mathbb{C})$.

Here are a couple ways to think about this. Within $\mathbb{C}$, you'll be able to find paths $a\to c$ and $b\to d$, which you can combine in $\mathbb{C}^2$ by either traversing at the same time (componentwise) or one after the other. Within the plane, you can traverse straight line segments between two points or, if you're trying to avoid a point on said line segment, around a semicircle containing the two points.

See if you can get an answer with these hints.

Comment: Sorry, but could you elaborate " which you can combine in $\mathbb{C}^2$ by either traversing at the same time (component-wise) or one after the other.   "

Comment: @Iampi For instance, if $\gamma_1:[0,1]\to\Bbb C$ satisfying $\gamma_1(0)=a,\gamma_1(1)=b$ is a path from $a$ to $b$ and $\gamma_2:[0.1]\to\Bbb C$ satisfying $\gamma_2(0)=c,\gamma_2(1)=d$ is a path from $c$ to $d$, then $(\gamma_1,\gamma_2):[0,1]\to\Bbb C^2$ is a path from $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$. Informally, this is traversing both paths at the same time.

Comment: In a space $X$, if you have a path $p:[0,1]\to X$ from $p(0)=u$ to $p(1)=v$ and a path $q:[0,1]\to X$ from $q(0)=v$ to $q(1)=w$, then there is a path $r:[0,2]\to X$ from $r(0)=u$ to $r(2)=w$ given by $$ r(t)=\begin{cases} p(t) & 0\le t\le 1 \\ q(t-1) & 1\le t\le 2 \end{cases}$$ Informally, this is traversing the two paths one after the other.

Comment: But why this path is entirely lying on the complement of diag$(\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Which path? You haven't given a specific path.

Comment: The path $(\gamma_1.\gamma_2):[0,1]\to \mathbb{C}^2$

Comment: But what did you choose $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ to be? You can't check if a path goes through ${\rm diag}(\Bbb C)$ if you haven't chosen what path to check.

Comment: I can choose $\gamma_1(t)=a(1-t)+bt$ and $\gamma_2(t)=c(1-t)+dt$.

Comment: In other words, two straight line segments. That's an idea. In general, though, those can intersect each other at some point in time. (For instance, if $a,c,b,d$ are the vertices of a square in $\Bbb C$, in that order.) Another thing you can do, that I haven't mentioned, is you can reparametrize. For instance, two line segments are only going to intersect at one point, and if they happen to intersect at a certain parameter $t$, then you can reparametrize one to fix that (so replace $t$ with $t^2$ in one of the formulas, say).

Comment: Sorry, but still I am unable to get the path from [0,1] to the space.

Comment: @Iampi You already mentioned the idea of two line segments. Geometrically, it should be clear that (assuming these are four distinct points) the only time these two paths cross (i.e. hit the same point at the same time $t$) is if the points form a rhombus. In that case, you can reparametrize by replacing $t$ with $t^2$ in one of the paths (so that path goes slower than it otherwise would have). And handle the case of $a,b,c,d$ not being distinct separately.

Comment: Okay, now I got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Like how $\Bbb R^3$ removing a line (an affine subspace of two lower dimension) is path-connected, $\Bbb R^4$ removing a plane (also an affine subspace of two lower dimension) should, by guessing, also be path-connected.

First have a look how $\Bbb R^3$ removing a line is path-connected. Consider $\Bbb R^3\setminus L$, where $L=\{(0,0,x_3)\}$. Consider the cylinder $C=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3):x_1^2+x_2^2=1\}$. The cylinder is path-connected, which you can actually see. Each point $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ on $\Bbb R^3\setminus L$ can be connected to $C$ by a straight line path that goes in the direction $(x_1,x_2,0)$ or its reverse direction. So the whole $\Bbb R^3\setminus L$ is path-connected.

For your case, the set would be $\Bbb R^4\setminus P$ with $P=\{(0,0,x_3,x_4)\}$. You again prove that the cylinder $C=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4):x_1^2+x_2^2=1\}$ is path-connected, and any point $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ on $\Bbb R^4\setminus P$ can be connected to the cylinder by the straight line path that goes in the direction $(x_1,x_2,0,0)$.

Comment: Indeed, $\mathbb{R}^4\setminus\mathbb{R}^2\simeq \mathbb{R}\times(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\mathbb{R})$.